# Solve the puzzle to complete the sequence

Tags: number-sequence

Solve the puzzle with the logic, what should the missing number in the last sequence

[image: Solve the puzzle with the logic, what should the number in the last sequence]

I found this on Facebook, and I don't know where it came from.

Comment: Not aware of it's original source. Found it on facebook without any answer so, posted it here.

Comment: @akash Thanks for the update. You should include as much information as you can in the question posting.

Answer (score 5):

This is possibly a stretch, but since there are no rules given, I give it a shot:

> B. $2$

The explanation

> The number from the top left hand side will be in the ones place in the bottom number ($2$ in the last case)
>
>  Take the number of zeros from the sum of the middle and the right hand top numbers. And put it in the tens place ($0$ in the last case).
>
>   So you get $02$ which is actually $2$.

It might not be the intended answer, but it definitely applies.

Comment: Your rule for the digit in the unit position makes sense, the tens digit is a bit of a stretch as you rightly pointed out :-). That said, this seems to be quite open-ended, so take my upvote!